# How to iterate through folder and get certain files from the subfolders grouped?

Tags: python, dictionary, xlsx, subdirectory, os.walk

I have a folder that contains several subfolders, each containing 3-4 files that I need.
I am trying to iterate through that folder and put all the files from each subfolder in a dictionary that is later dumped in a json file.

So far I've managed to do this for a single file and the json file looks like this:

[image]

and this is the code:

```
import os
import json
myDir = "\\\iads011n\\ContinuousTesting\\DailyTesting\\REPORTS"
filelist = []
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(myDir):
    for file in files:
        if (file.endswith('.xlsx') or file.endswith('.xls') or file.endswith('.XLS')) and "Release" in file and "Integrated" not in file:
            filelist.append(os.path.join(file))

myDict = dict(zip(range(len(filelist)), filelist))

result=[]
for k,v in myDict.items():
    result.append({'id' : k, 'name' : v})

with open('XLList.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(result, json_file)
```

But what I'm trying to achieve is this:

[image]

This is the folder:
[image]

And one of the subfolder contents looks like this:
[image]

**So basically what I need is all the xls/ xlsx files under the same subfolder grouped.
The major problem is that not all the subfolders contain the same items, some may have only one xlsx file or another may have only 3 or 4, etc.**

Comment: So each subfolder would have a different id? Also can you layout a sample file tree of your directory?

Comment: Also in your condition, you are checking `"Integrated" not in file` but in your expected output, they are included :D Also the `"version"` file isn't in the condition but is in the expected output. I'm voting to close this question due to unclear details.

Comment: yes so every subfolder has a different id. And also, the sample code is working for only one file, i had to match that file so that's why is "Integrated" not in file. Same for version.

Comment: but what i want is to have a dictionary/ list or any data type of objects and each object should have an id and the name of the xlsx files from every subfolder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that you do not "store" to which folder each file belongs. A solution would be the following:

```
result = []
for i, (path, subdirs, files) in enumerate(os.walk(myDir)): #use enumerate to track folder id
    subdir = {"id": i}
    j = 0 #file counter in subfolder
    for file in files:
        if (file.endswith('.xlsx') or file.endswith('.xls') or file.endswith('.XLS')) and "Release" in file and "Integrated" not in file:
            subdir[f"name{j}"] = file
            j += 1
    result.append(subdir)
```

### EDIT

To ignore folders with no useful files:

```
result = []
i = 0 #track folder id manually
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(myDir): 
    subdir = {}
    j = 0 #file counter in subfolder
    for file in files:
        if (file.endswith('.xlsx') or file.endswith('.xls') or file.endswith('.XLS')) and "Release" in file and "Integrated" not in file:
            subdir[f"name{j}"] = file
            j += 1
    if len(subdir) > 0:
        subdir = {"id": i}
        result.append(subdir)
        i += 1 #increase counter
```

Comment: thank u! that's exactly what i was looking for. but one problem would be that now i have like 3 times more ids because the subfolders may contain other folders that i don't care about. any idea how should i transfer to another list with only the objects that have an id and an name? an example: https://ibb.co/3r4nSM5

Comment: You have to check, if any file fulfills the last if condition. I edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

### Updated Solution for separating subfolder's files as separate object:

```
...  # other code before it

import re
results = []
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(myDir):
    id = your_algo_to_get_id() 
    data = {'id': id}
    for i, file in enumerate(files):
        if re.search(r"[\s\S]*release[\s\S]*\.xlsx?$", file, re.I) and
        "integrated" not in file.lower(): 
            data[f'name{i}'] = file
    results.append(data)  # output : [ { 'id': 0, 'name1': '...', ...}, {'id': 1, 'name1': '...'}, ..]
```

### Older Solution

Assuming `id = 0`:

```
result = {'id': 0}
for i, filename in enumerate(filelist):
    result[f'name{i}'] = filename
```

The json output of `result` will be:

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "name0": "some-filename.xlsx",
  "name1": "some-filename.xlsx",
  "name2": "some-filename.xlsx",
  "name3": "some-filename.xlsx",
  ...
}
```

`enumerate` is python's built-in function. You can also start it from 1, if you don't want to put `name0`.

```
result = {'id': 0}
for i, filename in enumerate(filelist, 1):
    ...
```

A suggestion for your code:

> ```
> for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(myDir):
>     for file in files:
>         if (file.endswith('.xlsx') or file.endswith('.xls') or file.endswith('.XLS')) and "Release" in file and "Integrated" not in file:
>             filelist.append(os.path.join(file))
> ```

I suggest using regex `r"xlsx?$"` with **ignorecase** to match filenames, so one condition is handling all your scenarios:

```
test_filenames = ["sample-name.XLSX", "sample-name.xlsx","sample-name.xls", "sample-name.XLS"]
for filename in test_filenames:
    if re.search(r"xlsx?$", filename, re.I):
        # it's matching
```

Comment: i think i didn't make my self clear enough. sorry for that. but what i'm trying to achieve is that every json object should contain an id and the name of the files from the subfolder. so basically each json object is a subfolder containing the id (given by me) and the names of the xls files. this is an example of one object: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OMI4.png

Comment: See updated solution, hope it works with slight modifications.

Comment: it's working well but i have the same problem as from @nckstr15 's solution. that i get an id for each subfolder. is there any way that i can get rid of the empty ids? like when looping through the folder to only search in the 1st subfolder? like the 1st child.

Comment: https://ibb.co/3r4nSM5 this is an example

Comment: You mean ignore subfolders that don't have any file within your given criteria? if yes then you can ignore it at the start of the loop:

```
id = 1
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(myDir):
    data = {}
    for i, file in enumerate(files):
        if re.search(r"[\s\S]*release[\s\S]*\.xlsx?$", file, re.I) and
        "integrated" not in file.lower(): 
            data[f'name{i}'] = file
    if not len(data):
        continue  # skip it
    id += 1
    data['id'] = id
    results.append(data)
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/faizanalhassan/c1403172c98c79c3c2b66ecd58a66725